# If we have sequences $X_n,Y_m \in L^2[0,1]$, for $n \neq m$, why does it follow that $\mathbb{E}[X_nY_m] = \int_0^1X_nY_m \, dP$ for all $n,m \geq 0$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, normed-spaces

If we have sequences $X_n,Y_m \in L^2[0,1]$, for $n \neq m$, why does it follow that $\mathbb{E}[X_nY_m] = \int_0^1X_nY_m \, dP$ for all $n,m \geq 0$  where $P$ is the probability measure on the space $L^2[0,1]$? This appears to be different than how expectations are normally defined, is there a trick to the form above? Thanks!

Comment: If $\Omega$ is the sample space and $X(\omega)$ and $Y(\omega)$ are random variables defined over $\omega \in \Omega$, then $Z(\omega)=X(\omega)Y(\omega)$ is just another random variable.  So $E[Z] \overset{def}{=} \int Z(\omega)dP(\omega) = \int X(\omega)Y(\omega)dP(\omega)$.

Comment: The translation of $\int Z(\omega) dP(\omega)$ to standard PDF terminology is given in Michael Hardy's answer.  Using "$f_Z(z)dz$" as "$dP(\omega)$" gives $E[Z]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} zf_Z(z)dz$.  Using "$f_{XY}(x,y)dxdy$" as "$dP(\omega)$" gives $E[Z]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xyf_{XY}(x,y)dxdy$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase "$P$ is the probability measure" could be construed as meaning the *only* probability measure, so "$P$ is *a* probability measure" is more appropriate here.

It's not a measure on $L^2[0,1]$ but rather on Borel subsets of $[0,1]$.  Informally one says it's a measure on $[0,1]$.  The space $L^2[0,1]$ is the set of functions $X : [0,1] \to \mathbb C$ for which $\int_{[0,1]} |X|^2\,dP<\infty$.

The usual definition of the expected value of a random variable $X$ on a probability space $\Omega$ with probability measure $P$ is
$$
\operatorname{E}(X) = \int_\Omega X\,dP.
$$
To see how this is related to the way in which expected values are often computed in courses not relying on measure theory, you might think of it as $f(x)\,dx = dP(x)$ where $f$ is the density.  Then you have
$$
\operatorname{E}(X) = \int_\Omega X\,dP = \int_0^1 x \Big( f(x)\,dx\Big).
$$